# Add value in a variable using for loop - Python Flask

Tags: python

I'm new in python + flask, and having a hard time to add a value beside the variable value. The variable text should be on array value. 
**This is the output i wanted to :**

text123
area123
testing123
**The output ended up like this :**

['text 
\narea 
\ntesting123', 'text 
\narea 
\ntesting123', 'text 
\narea 
\ntesting123']

This is my code so far

```
    text = request.form['title']
    value = "123"
    textarray = []
    for txt in text:
        text4 = text.replace('\r', '<br>')
        output = text4 + value
        textarray.append(output)

    return render_template('index.html', text=textarray)
```

Thank you for your kind answers

Comment: `\r` should be `\r\n`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried \r\n but the output only remove the \n not the output i wanted to.

Comment: I thought that was the problem you were having.

Comment: `text.replace` should be `txt.replace`?

Comment: The request.form['title'] is the textarea value, I wanted to add the "123" on each word.

Comment: Seems like you should be looping over `text.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text.split()` to split the input into words

```
text = request.form['title']
value = "123"
textarray = [word + value for word in text.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your elaboration you need to use split:

```
text = request.form['title'].split()
value = "123"
textarray = []
for txt in text:
    text4 = txt.replace('\r', '<br>')
    output = text4 + value
    textarray.append(output)
```